# How to override a column name in sqlalchemy using reflection and descriptive syntax

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hello I'm trying to port a legacy application to python with sqlalchemy.

The application's existing database has about 300 tables and in every table there is a colum named def such as :

```
create table accnt (
    code varchar(20)
  , def varchar(50) --for accnt definition
  , ...
)
```

So when with declarative syntax and reflection I can easily create my class as :

```
class Accnt(Base):
    __table__ = Table('accnt', metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with=engine)
```

But when I try to reach *def* column I eventually get an error. For example :

```
q = session.query(Accnt)
for row in q:
    print q.def
```

Because *def* is a reserved word for python :(

To overcome this issue I can create my class as :

```
class Accnt(Base):
    __table__ = Table('accnt', metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with=engine)
    __mapper_args__ = {'column_prefix':'_'}
```

But putting a _ in front of every column name is boring and not fancy.

What I'd like to do is access def column with another name / ( key ?).

Any ideas?

--- Edit ---
( Editing original post as requested by [TokenMacGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65696/tokenmacguy) )

While I've accepted [TokenMacGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65696/tokenmacguy)'s answer I've tried it before as :

```
engine = create_engine('firebird://sysdba:masterkey@127.0.0.1/d:\\prj\\db2\\makki.fdb?charse‌​t=WIN1254', echo=False) 
metadata = MetaData() 
DbSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine) 
Base = declarative_base() 

class Accnt(Base):
    __table__ = Table('accnt', metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with=engine) 
    _def = Column("def", String(50))
```

And I've got
    sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't add additional column 'def' when specifying table
error..

The main difference between me and TokenMacGuy is

```
mine       : _table_ ....
TokenMcGuy : __tablename__ = 'accnt'
             __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}
```

and metadata binding...

So, why my previous attemp generated an error ?

Comment: Because you are setting the class to use a Table that you have already made, as opposed to letting your class automatically generate it from your attribues. You cant create more columns after setting a __table__

Comment: @jdi Your comment makes much more sense after TokenMacGuy's explanation. But I think both of you are saying the same thing while TMG explains alittle bit more :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can have your cake and eat it too.  Define the columns you want to rename; sqlalchemy will automatically infer any columns you don't mention.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import *
>>> from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
>>> 
>>> engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
>>> 
>>> engine.execute("""
... create table accnt (
...     id integer primary key,
...     code varchar(20),
...     def varchar(50)
... )
... """)
<sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy object at 0x2122750>
>>> 
>>> Base = declarative_base()
>>> 
>>> Base.metadata.bind = engine
>>> 
>>> class Accnt(Base):
...     __tablename__ = 'accnt'
...     __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}
...     def_ = Column('def', String)
... 
>>> Accnt.def_
<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x2122e90>
>>> Accnt.code
<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x2127090>
>>>
```

EDIT:

By supplying a `__table__` argument, you're telling the declarative extension that you already have a properly configured `Table` that you'd like to use.  But that's not true; you want to have the `def` column referred to by another name in the class.  By using `__tablename__` and `__table_args__`, you defer the construction of the table until after you've told declarative how you want to use that table.  There's no elegant work-around if you are dead set on using `__table__`.  You can provide a `property` that aliases the column or you may be able to specify the column as `_def = getattr(__table__.c, 'def')`.

Really, you should just use `__tablename__`;  It's both more convenient and more flexible, and this is a great example of why.

(as an aside, it's most conventional to give alternate identifiers a trailing underscore instead of a leading underscore, use `def_` instead of `_def`; leading underscores usually signify that the name is 'private' or 'an implementation detail', if the name is meant to be public, but looks like a private name, it may cause more confusion than is necessary)

Comment: Thanks ! I tried to that way with below code
 
`engine = create_engine('firebird://sysdba:masterkey@127.0.0.1/d:\\prj\\db2\\makki.fdb?charset=WIN1254', echo=False)`

`metadata = MetaData()`

`DbSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)`

`Base = declarative_base()`

`class Accnt(Base):`

  `__table__ = Table('accnt', metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with=engine)`

  `_def = Column("def", String(50))`


But I always got 'sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't add additional column 'def' when specifying __table__'

Error... What is the diference between these two aproaches ?

Comment: @ctengiz - I think its because the way you are doing it, the Table has already been generated. If you want to specify different named attributes for your columns, you need to do it inline.

Comment: Please post your code in your original question;  It's almost impossible to make sense of it when you put it in a comment.

Comment: Before your answer I've found a dirty solution : `Accnt.defi = getattr(Accnt, 'def')`

Which is not elegant and pythonic and probably will lead other problems ..

Answer (score 3):

You could define your Table this way:

```
mymetadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=mymetadata)

class Accnt(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'accnt'

    code = Column(String(20))
    def_ = Column(String(50))
```

Comment: I know, but I'd like to use reflection. Without reflection It would be huge amount of coding. Because the database I'm trying to access is an existing database with many tables...

Comment: TokenMacGuy does pretty much the same thing, but with way better examples and clarity :-)

Answer (score 1):

This may be too much brute force, but another approach is to use the `sqlacodegen` library to auto-generate all the models for your DB, then alter those manually, or tweak `sqlacodegen` to build the models using your conventions.  It has support for mapping reserved words to other symbols.

See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlacodegen.  Nice tool.