# One To Many Relationship definition with reflection and declarative syntax in sqlalchemy gives join condition error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to set One-To-Many relationship on an existing database.

Simplified DDL is :

```
create table accnt (
  code varchar(20) not null
  , def varchar(100)
  , constraint pk_accnt primary key (code)
);

commit;

create table slorder (
  code varchar(20) not null
  , def varchar(100)
  , dt date
  , c_accnt varchar(20) not null
  , constraint pk_slorder primary key (code)
  , constraint fk_slorder_accnt foreign key (c_accnt)
     references accnt (code)
     on update cascade on delete cascade
);

commit;
```

SqlAlchemy Code :

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import *

engine = create_engine('firebird://sysdba:masterkey@127.0.0.1/d:\\prj\\db2\\makki.fdb?charset=WIN1254', echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.bind = engine

class Accnt(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'accnt'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

    defi = Column('def', String(100))

class SlOrder(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'slorder'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

    defi = Column("def", String(100))
    accnt = relationship('Accnt', backref='slorders')
```

gives

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship SlOrder.accnt.  Specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.  If 'secondary' is present, 'secondaryjoin' is needed as well.
```

error.

My possible solutions to this problem are :

**1**

```
class SlOrder(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'slorder'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

    defi = Column("def", String(100))
    c_accnt = Column("c_accnt", String(20), ForeignKey('accnt.code'))

    accnt = relationship('Accnt', backref='slorders')
```

But this approach needs that I have to add every foreign key constraint column manually,  which leads to making reflection useles. (Because I've got many columns references to other tables.)

**2**

```
class SlOrder(Base):
    __table__ = Table('accnt', metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with=engine)
    accnt = relationship('Accnt', backref='slorders', primaryjoin=(__table__.c_accnt==Accnt.code))
```

This approach has an another consequence (please see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679893/how-to-override-a-column-name-in-sqlalchemy-using-reflection-and-descriptive-synt))

So what am I missing? What is the best way to define a relationship both using reflection and declarative syntax?

EDIT :

I've figured that SqlAlchemy finds and builds relationships if child table has only one reference to parent table.

But if child table has more than one reference as :

```
create table slorder (
  code varchar(20) not null
  , def varchar(100)
  , dt date
  , c_accnt varchar(20) not null
  , c_accnt_ref  varchar(20) 
  , constraint pk_slorder primary key (code)
  , constraint fk_slorder_accnt foreign key (c_accnt)
     references accnt (code)
     on update cascade on delete cascade

  , constraint fk_slorder_accnt_ref foreign key (c_accnt_ref)
     references accnt (code)
     on update cascade on delete no action
);
```

the above error occurs.

So is it expected behavior of SqlAlchemy to give error if there is more than one relation between two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should automatically reflect `ForeignKey` and use for the relationship without any changes.
Just some ideas to explore the issue though:

1. Make sure you do not have multiple `ForeignKey`'s to the same parent table or else you must specify the join condition using `primaryjoin` parameter, because SA cannot automatically decide which one to use.
2. Make sure you actually have a `ForeignKey` defined in the `slorder` table (as shown in the code example)
3. Check if maybe there is a non-default `schema` defined for some tables and maybe you need to define one in your tables `_table_args__ = {'schema': 'my_schema'}` (Just guessing, as I do not know `firebird` so no idea about schema support there really)
4. Check/Debug the reflection step: [sqlalchemy/dialects/firebird/base.py](http://hg.sqlalchemy.org/sqlalchemy/file/650f805af70c/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/firebird/base.py) has `get_foreign_keys`. Check the SQL statement `fkqry` and execute it directly on your database to see if it reflects your `ForeignKey`. If not, try to find out why.

Comment: 1. Yes I do have

2. Firebird does not have schema support

3. SqlAlchemy correctly finds my foreign key and its properties.

Comment: Well, you really answered your question. Unfortunately your original (simplified) code did not expose the problem, which is exactly existence of multiple FKs to the parent table. For completeness, I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll accept your answer because it is correct :) I could not find proper way to set up primaryjoin when using reflection and declarative style so I tested `1.` and it worked. Trying to set relation just typing `accnt = relationship('Accnt', backref='slorders', primaryjoin=(Accnt.code==c_accnt))` and omitting column definition gives `NameError: name 'c_accnt' is not defined` error.

Comment: I think you can try to define stringified match condition: `accnt = relationship('Accnt', backref='slorders', primaryjoin = "slorder.c_accnt==accnt.code"))` and it will work without defining `__table__` and still using just `__tablename__`

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to add `ForeignKey` in child table.

By the way of define `ForeignKey` you can assign value to `c_accnt` and also assign object of parent to `accnt`.

Internally sqlalchemy fire the query which you wrote in primaryjoin. If there is no foreign key then model can't understand on which field it has to run a query.

You can use any both way. But I personally prefer `ForeignKey` and `relation` to `ForeignKey`. This way you have to write some more code but, it will give flexibility to assign value plus object directly.