# How to deal with space in database table field when using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am using python's sqlalchemy to interact with my database. The issue that i am facing is that in one of my tables, a field has a space in it's name, it's called "ALLOCATION CODE". As a consequence of that, when i am supposed to do an update to the field, i can't reference it as it is a not a valid class member name. The easy way but not feasible is to remove the space but i am afraid it is going to cause a mayhem in the broader system. So i am wondering is there a workaround? I think there are a couple of posts already here about column names with spaces but i believe the use case is different as the classes are not reflected. Thanks in advance.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, and_, Column, String
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from sqlalchemy import exc
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

CONNECTION_STRING = 'REMOVED'

engine = create_engine(CONNECTION_STRING, convert_unicode=True)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
db_session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


table_a_record = Base.classes.TableA

def db_update_table_a(id, allocation_code):
    s = db_session()
    try:
        record_to_update = s.query(table_a_record).filter(table_a_record.Id == id).first()
        record_to_update.Allocation Code = allocation_code
        s.flush()
        s.commit()
        return True, 'Success'
    except exc.IntegrityError as e:
        s.rollback()
        logger.error('Failed to update row, exception: {}'.format(e))
        return False, 'Integrity Error'
    except Exception as e:
        s.rollback()
        logger.error('Failed to update row, exception: {}'.format(e))
        return False, 'Unknown Error'
    finally:
        s.close()
```

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215759/sqlalchemy-reflecting-tables-and-columns-with-spaces ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679893/how-to-override-a-column-name-in-sqlalchemy-using-reflection-and-descriptive-syn is also a valid approach.

Comment: I will give it a go when i get back to the office on Monday. Thanks!

Comment: The approach in that first link you posted did the trick. I wish i had seen it earlier.